# Are inline functions completely deleted after build?

Tags: c++

```
__forceinline
int myPoorFunction(int i) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    return 15;
}

int main() {
    myPoorFunction(1);
}
```

After building in this way, are the inline functions completely deleted during the build? Should I take some security measures like hook protection for myPoorFunction like my other functions?

Comment: Looks to me like they are still there (but unused) after compilation with msvc. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/53Mvvc7s7)

Comment: Given "The compiler treats the inline expansion options and keywords as suggestions. There's no guarantee that functions will be inlined. You can't force the compiler to inline a particular function, even with the `__forceinline` keyword. " ... the answer depends on whether or not the inline function is *actually* inlined by the compiler.

Comment: It's up to the compiler whether to leave them in as stand alone functions or remove them completely. If they are not exported (have internal linkage) I would *expect* most compilers to remove them (at least when optimization is turned on) or for the linker to remove them, but I don't think you have any guarantees as per the standard.

Comment: The standard does not mandate what is in the final executable. (If a compiler wanted to, it could add unused functions that you did not write to the executable.) Do you want to focus your question on a specific compiler (or specific compilers)?

Comment: @Eljay `__forceinline` does have some effect though, in my experience.

Comment: The name `__forceinline` isn't well chosen, as it is more a "Pretty please, inline this". And you can enable a diagnostic to get reports where it wasn't inlined.

Comment: @BoP    Maybe you should convince the developers of compilers that support `__forceinline` to rename it to `__pray_inline`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo but it isn't called, so it doesn't matter if it could be intercepted in a hook

Comment: @Caleth Probably, but I got the impression OP didn't want to have even traces of it in there. I admit I don't know msvc very well so perhaps I left debugging info in there by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: unspecified by the standard. Don't assume it happens.
Longer answer: Unspecified by the standard, so each compiler can do whatever it sees fit.
In general, compilers are allowed to perform whatever optimizations they see fit as long as you wont notice it. For example, if in your code you took the address of a function marked with `inline` and did something with it (for whichever reason), it can't remove the function from the output.
Otherwise, completely removing a piece of code that is never referenced from the compilation result falls under "whatever they see fit", so maybe.
The `inline` keyword (for functions, it is a little different with variables afaik) is a suggestions or hint. The compiler is not bound by it.